# Set view header full width (css child conflict)

Tags: theming

I created a drupal website using the foundation theme.
At the page level the content is put inside a container.
Now I created a view and I want the header of this view (using an entity rendered entity) to be full width.

But the page layout is inside a container so the child (views template) cannot exceed it's width. How can I set the header to full width without breaking the page layout?

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? It's not per se a css question. It's about page to node structure

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I must admit this does seem like an HTML/CSS issue. The short answer would be to restructure your theme's HTML/CSS as necessary to accommodate your design. I don't think there's much Drupal core or a module could do to do that restructuring for you, unless maybe you do something drastic like moving to Panels. If you can tell us in basic HTML/CSS terms how you would make that `<div>` appear as full width (which is the crux of the issue), we can probably tell you how to make that happen in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Create header content as a seperate block and place it in the desired region. Set block visibility as views content.

Comment: But it should be kept dynamic. Different headers for different views. Is that possible using your solution?

Comment: Yes. It will be. you should set visibility of block as view page path only.

Comment: I guess I should use the block views visibility module?

Answer (score 0):

change the page layout in page.tpl.php:
move the container up the DOM structure until you get 100% width,
this will result in closing the parent(s) of the container,
having the container, and opening the parent(s) again.

or create a new region that will be in 100% width scope, and place the block there

Answer (score 0):

best thing to do is just comment/hide of most of the html/php in page.tpl and then go from there.

*First* way to solve issues relating to css is go in views and go through all format/field and make sure there is no extra html/css markup.

Second best thing is to get CSS formatter class module and go in manage displays of that view and set a new css class and update the .css with a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create a sub-theme based on your current theme and make the page.tpl to full width.

2 - Install theme-key module.

3 - Create a rule to switch theme based on the view you want.